# reading variables buried in java exception handling

Tags: java, exception

I am writing a function to take a text file and count how many lines it has while outputting the lines to an array of strings. Doing this I have several exceptions I need to look out for. The class function has several variables that should have a scope throughout the function but when I write a value to the function inside of an exception, the return statement cannot find it.  I've moved the declaration around and nothing helps

The value returned "h5Files" "Might not have been initialized" Since I don't know how long the array will be I cannot initialize it to a certain length. I do this within the code and I need a way to tell the return statement that I now have a values

Here is the code

```
public String[] ReadScanlist(String fileIn){

    int i;
    String directory ="c:\\data\\"; // "\" is an illegal character
    System.out.println(directory);
    int linereader = 0;
    String h5Files[];
    File fileToRead = new File(directory + fileIn); 
    System.out.println(fileToRead);


    try {
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fileToRead); // open this file

        }
    catch(FileNotFoundException exc) {
        System.out.println("File Not Found");
        }


    try{
        //read bytes until EOF is detected
        do {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileToRead);// Need to convert to reader
            LineNumberReader lineToRead = new LineNumberReader(fr); // Use line number reader class


            //
            while (lineToRead.readLine() != null){
                linereader++;
                }

            linereader = 0;
            lineToRead.setLineNumber(0); //reset line number
            h5Files = new String[linereader];
            while (lineToRead.readLine() != null){
                h5Files[linereader] = lineToRead.readLine(); // deposit string into array
                linereader++;
                }
            return h5Files;
            }
        while(i !=-1); // When i = -1 the end of the file has been reached    
        }
    catch(IOException exc) {
        System.out.println("Error reading file.");
        }

    try{
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fileToRead);
        fin.close(); // close the file
        }
    catch(IOException exc) {
        System.out.println("Error Closing File");
        }
    return h5Files;
    }
```

Comment: You can make use of a List (e.g. ArrayList) for the lines instead of an Array. Also you reset your h5Files array with 0 slots, so there will be an IndexOutOfBoundException, i'd guess.

Comment: What do you expect it to `return` where there is an `Exception` and your initialisation code hasn't been run? In the best case it would be `null`...

Comment: very good comments I will look into the list and I was going to use a null for an exception. Thank you I will attempt to implement the suggestions now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is very very odd. For example these two blocks make no sense:

```
try {
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fileToRead); // open this file

    }
catch(FileNotFoundException exc) {
    System.out.println("File Not Found");
    }

try{
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fileToRead);
    fin.close(); // close the file
    }
catch(IOException exc) {
    System.out.println("Error Closing File");
    }
```

I don't know what you think they do, but besides the first one leaking memory, they do nothing at all. The comments are more worrying, they suggest that you need to do more reading on IO in Java.

Deleting those blocks and tidying the code a (moving declarations, formatting) gives this:

```
public String[] ReadScanlist(String fileIn) {
    String directory = "c:\\data\\";
    String h5Files[];
    File fileToRead = new File(directory + fileIn);
    try {   
        int i = 0;
        do {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileToRead);
            LineNumberReader lineToRead = new LineNumberReader(fr);
            int linereader = 0;
            while (lineToRead.readLine() != null) {
                linereader++;
            }

            linereader = 0;
            lineToRead.setLineNumber(0);
            h5Files = new String[linereader];
            while (lineToRead.readLine() != null) {
                h5Files[linereader] = lineToRead.readLine();                    
                linereader++;
            }
            return h5Files;
        } while (i != -1);
    } catch (IOException exc) {
        System.out.println("Error reading file.");
    }
    return h5Files;
}
```

My first bone of contention is the `File` related code. First, `File` abstracts from the underlying OS, so using `/` is absolutely fine. Second, there is a reason `File` has a [`File`, `String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29) constructor, this code should read:

```
File directory = new File("c:/data");
File fileToRead = new File(directory, fileIn);
```

But it should really be using the new `Path` API anyway (see below).

So, you declare `h5Files[]`. You then proceed to read the whole file to count the lines. You then assign `h5Files[]` to an array of the correct size. Finally you fill the array.

If you have an error *anywhere* before you assign `h5Files[]` you have not initialised it and therefore cannot return it. This is what the compiler is telling you.

I don't know what `i` does in this code, it is assigned to `0` at the top and then never reassigned. This is an infinite loop.

So, you need to rethink your logic. I would recommend throwing an `IOException` if you cannot read the file. **Never** `return null` - this is an anti-pattern and leads to all those thousands of `null` checks in your code. If you never `return null` you will never have to check for it.

May I suggest the following alternative code:

If you are on Java 7:

```
public String[] ReadScanlist(String fileIn) throws IOException {
    final Path root = Paths.get("C:/data");
    final List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(root.resolve(fileIn), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    return lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
}
```

Or, if you have Java 8:

```
public String[] ReadScanlist(String fileIn) throws IOException {
    final Path root = Paths.get("C:/data");
    try (final Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(root.resolve(fileIn), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        return lines.toArray(String[]::new);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Since I don't know how long the array will be I cannot initialize it
>   to a certain length.

I don't think an array is the correct solution for you then - not to say it can't be done, but you would be re-inventing the wheel.

I would suggest you use a LinkedList instead, something like:

```
LinkedList<String> h5Files = new LinkedList<>();
h5Files.add(lineToRead.readLine());
```

Alternatively you could re-invent the wheel by setting the array to an arbritary value, say 10, and then re-size it whenever it gets full, something like this:

```
h5Files = new String[10];
if (linereader = h5Files.size())
{
    String[] temp = h5Files;
   h5Files = new String[2 * linereader];
   for (int i = 0; i < linereader; i++)
  {
     h5Files[i] = temp[i];
  }

}
```

Either one of these solutions would allow you to initialize the array (or array alternative) in a safe constructor, prior to your try block, such that you can access it if any exceptions are thrown

Comment: `System.arraycopy` exists for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem. Please take a look on digested version of your code with my comments.

```
  String h5Files[]; // here you define the variable. It still is not initialized.
  try{
        ..................
        do {
            h5Files = new String[linereader]; // here you initialize the variable
        } while(i !=-1); // When i = -1 the end of the file has been reached    
        ..................
    catch(IOException exc) {
        // if you are here the variable is still not initialized
        System.out.println("Error reading file.");
    }

    // you continue reading file even if exception was thrown while opening the file
```

I think that now the problem is clearer. You try to open the file and count lines. If you succeed you create array. If not (i.e. when exception is thrown) you catch the exception  but still continue reading the file. But in this case you array is not initialized.

Now how to fix this?

Actually if you failed to read the file first time you cannot continue. This may happen for example if file does not exist. So, you should either return when first exception is thrown or just do not catch it at all. Indeed there is nothing to do with the file if exception was thrown at any phase. Exception is not return code. This is the reason that exceptions exist.

So, just do not catch exceptions at all. Declare your method as `throws IOException` and remove all try/catch blocks.